# How can I fix the double rendering problem using Bootstrap 4 collapse element

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to animate the content of a Bootstrap 4 collapse element, but I'm getting a double render - one unanimated followed by the animated render. This doesn't happen with other bootstrap elements I've tried. Only the collapse element.

https://codesandbox.io/s/collapse-alert-forked-6z6e9?file=/src/styles.css:233-388

Is there a way to fix this so that it doesn't render before the animation is applied?

Answer (score 0):

modified the selector to include collapsing. appears to work for my needs.

```
.collapsing,
.collapse {
  animation: opacity 1s, border 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```